# how to make use of web service in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, web-services

I'm just starting to make use of webService in iphone apps.Firstly I want to add Facebook login in my app. for that I have downloaded fresh copy of `Facebook SDK` BUT I can not install it , at the end it says "installation failed" every time. and can any one put well form steps to make use of web service?

Answer (score 0):

Install the Facebook SDK from this link: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

If you only want to integrate sharing via Twitter or Facebook: take a look at this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/

There are many ways to connect to a webservice, you have to be more specific in order for us to help you with the thing you want to accomplish. But take a look at this link:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/ and http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-json-twitter-api/